# How to open X509 certificate in java?

Tags: java, exception, x509certificate, pki

I was trying to open a crt certificate in java and hence thereby get some parameters from the crt. I used the following code:

```
inStream = new FileInputStream("sbi.crt");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
```

When I run the code, the compiler throws certificate exception at line 2. Is it because of the certificate that I'm using? Or what changes in code should I make?

Or is there any alternative way to access a certificate and extract the details?

Comment: what exception and where

Comment: This is the exception thrown :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Unhandled exception type CertificateException
 Unhandled exception type CertificateException

 at filehand.handle.main(handle.java:30)

Comment: here line 30 is line 2

Comment: `Unresolved compilation problems`, any compile errors or runtime

Comment: No..thats the only error shown during compilation.Pls help

Comment: pleas epost some more code, how are you handling exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the code, the compiler throws certificate exception at line 2.

No it doesn't. The compiler doesn't throw exceptions. It prints compilation errors.

> Is it because of the certificate that I'm using?

No.

> Or what changes in code should I make?

Catch the exception named in the error message, or declare it to be thrown by the method.